# NoReverseMatch , Reverse for 'profilepage' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profilepage/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, html, django

```
def profilki(request):

profilki = profile.objects.all()

context = {'profilki':profilki }

return render(request,'base/profilki.html',context)


def profilepage(request,pk): user = Trainingvalue.objects.get(id=pk) trainingplan = Trainingvalue.objects.all() profilepage= profile.objects.get(id=pk) user_training= Trainingvalue.objects.filter(user=profilepage.user) context
        ={‘user_training’:user_training,‘user’:user,‘profilepage’:profilepage, ‘trainingplan’:trainingplan,}
        
        return render(request, 'base/profilepage.html' , context) url : path (‘profilepage/str:pk/’,views.profilepage, name=“profilepage”)
```

profilepage in context
profile page has an attribute id
profilepage.id entity does not provide value - yet i can access it through the borwser…

so technically this should work in html template:

profile

i get error:

```
Reverse for 'profilepage' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profilepage/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/\\Z']
```

Comment: Please don't put your code in blockquotes, use triple backticks to surround your code `\`\`\`` See the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to see how to format your posts

Comment: Does your code look readable to you in the post? Turning it from / to a blockquote has removed the newlines and indentation, please [edit] again. Also see how to write a [mre].

Comment: Your code is still unreadable

Answer (score 0):

profilepage/pk/ needs an id to be sent to the backend. Its a detail call.
But you are sending "" empty.